# How to run Nunit test in F# from console

Tags: visual-studio, f#, nunit, nunit-console

I have a project written in `F# 4.1` which uses `Nunit 3.6.1`. I use `VisualStudio 2017` to build a projects and `NUnit Console Runner 3.6.1` to run tests. But when i try to run my tests a receve an error:

> C:\projects\AzureLogsDownloader\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1\tools>nunit3-console.exe "C:\projects\AzureLogsDownloader\AzureLogs.Core.Tests\bin\Debug\AzureLogs.Core.Tests.dll"
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.(HRSULT: 0x80131040)

I tried to copy `FSharp.Core` to test runner's folder, but it doesn't help.

How fix this issue and to run my tests?

Comment: Check DLL versions: they all should match or you should add binding redirects to your config.

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework is used?

Comment: @BentTranberg 4.5.2

Comment: @FyodorSoikin where should i check these DLLs? 
i changed AzureLogs.Core.Tests.dll to .exe, after build i can run both applications -> In build folder all DLLs are compatible

Comment: I don't know whether there's any relation to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665926/cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-fsharp-core-4-4-1-0-when-using-vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

There are just few necessary steps:

1. Create `app.config` file in your test project
2. Add bindingRedirects like shown in this sample (I assume that you are on NUnit 3.6.1):

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="4.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NUnit.Framework" publicKeyToken="2638cd05610744eb" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="3.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. Result is the same

Comment: Try to change "4.4.1.0" to "4.4.0.0". The reason I think this may work, is that you are using .NET Framework 4.5.2.