# Why does dotnet-fantomas need FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0?

Tags: f#, nuget, lint

Trying to make `dotnet-fantomas` work, I installed both `Fantomas` and `dotnet-fantomas` from `Nuget` and added the lines

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-fantomas" Version="2.7.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to my `.fsproj` file. Then I added the folder where `dotnet-fantomas.exe` was installed to the Windows path.

Next I opened a command prompt in a folder with some `.fs` files and tried to run

```
dotnet-fantomas Asset.fs --force
```

I got the error message below.  `dotnet-fantomas` is asking for `FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0` and I have `FSharp.Core` version 4.3.4. Browsing in the `Nuget Package Manager` that is the latest version available. My project has `4.4.3.0` as Target runtime and `.NET Framework 4.6.1` as Target Framework.

What am I missing?

```
C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\Fractal13>dotnet-fantomas Asset.fs --force
The following exception occurs while formatting stdin: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Fantomas.CodeFormatterImpl.createFormatContextNoChecker(String fileName, String source)
   at Fantomas.CodeFormatter.FormatDocument(String fileName, String source, FormatConfig config)
   at Fantomas.Cmd.Program.processSourceString(Boolean isFsiFile, String s, TextWriter tw, FormatConfig config)
   at Fantomas.Cmd.Program.stringToFile@185(FSharpRef`1 force, FSharpRef`1 profile, FSharpRef`1 fsi, String s, String outFile, FormatConfig config)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Force writing original contents to Asset.fs.
```

Comment: The *package* version isn't the same as the DLL version. Do you have a bad redirect in your app.config perhaps? Which version of Visual Studio are you using? The latest is VS 2017 15.7. There were quite a few problems with version mixups about a year ago, check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665926/cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-fsharp-core-4-4-1-0-when-using-vs-2017)

Comment: I am using VS 2017 15.7, which I downloaded yesterday. My app.config has only the following: `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"`

Comment: I looked at the question you suggested. One comment by Bent Tranberg has the following:  "your problem could simply be that you need to add a reference to FSharp.Core 4.4.1.0 (Not Microsoft.FSharp...) in your C# project(s) where this error appears. " This looks interesting but is a bit over my head. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: That's because F# versioning is [a mess](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/tooling/FST-1004-versioning-plan.md)

Comment: Mind-boggling. How can a mere mortal without superpowers handle this?