# Strange IIS error message cannot find f#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, f#

Just gave IIS full permissions for the project, but on launch I get this error?

> Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

not sure how helpful this will be but here is the stack trace

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core,
>   Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
>   IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +191
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +161
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord
>   caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly,
>   RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[]
>   attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean&
>   isVarArg) +155
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +607 
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType) +144
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String
>   friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +190
>
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String friendlyName,
>   IList`1 errors) +68
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName,
>   IList`1 errorDetails) +89    Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String
>   startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +30
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +165
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +37
>   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target,
>   Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +135
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +160
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +580
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +165
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +353
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +341
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +107    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +688

thanks all.

Comment: What do you mean by "Just gave IIS full permissions for the project"?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665926/cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-fsharp-core-4-4-1-0-when-using-vs-2017 Hope this helps.